# Need to access the array of Child object from the Parent object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
PostResponseOutput(TextedValue):Promise<any>
{
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://NHSSQLCHNE8105:8081/ctakes-web-rest/service/analyzejson? 
pipeline=default',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    body: TextedValue
};
await request(options, callback);
async function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = await JSON.parse(body);    
}  
}}
```

Using the npm requests i am getting the body of the json and using the 
JSON.parse(body) Converts the below JSON file to list of objects. I need to 
access the array which is in the child object. But since the child object 
gets changed dynamically based on the input which we provide.I am unable to 
get the array of the child object in code. 
   Can anyone please help in getting the array from the PARENT OBJECT WITHOUT 
ACCESSING THE Child object.

I need to remove the Dynamically changing child objects and need to access 
its array from the Parent Object.
   Note: PARENT OBject will not be changing  based on the input . it will have the value or not based on the input

## JSON File

```
{
// This is the Allergy Object. which doesn't have any Value for the input 
Admit
    "Allergy": {},
// This is the Others Object. which has 1 Value for the input Admit
    "Others": {
        **"Health Care Activity~T058~Hospital admission":** [
            "codingScheme: SNOMEDCT_US",
            "code: 32485007",
            "cui: C0184666",
            "semanticType: Health Care Activity",
            "tui: T058",
            "preferredtext: Hospital admission"
        ]
    },
// This is the AnatomicalSiteMention Object. which doesn't have any Value 
for the input Admit
    "AnatomicalSiteMention": {},
// This is the MedicationMention Object. which doesn't have any Value for the 
input Admit
    "MedicationMention": {},
// This is the DrugChangeStatusAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any 
Value for the input Admit
    "DrugChangeStatusAnnotation": {},
// This is the DrugChangeStatusAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any 
Value for the input Admit
    "StrengthAnnotation": {},
// This is the Request Object. which doesn't have any Value for the input 
Admit
    "Request": {},
// This is the FractionStrengthAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any 
Value for the input Admit
    "FractionStrengthAnnotation": {},
// This is the FrequencyUnitAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any Value 
for the input Admit
    "FrequencyUnitAnnotation": {},
// This is the DiseaseDisorderMention Object. which doesn't have any Value 
for the input Admit
    "DiseaseDisorderMention": {},
// This is the FamilyMember Object. which doesn't have any Value for the 
input Admit
    "FamilyMember": {},
// This is the SignSymptomMention Object. which doesn't have any Value for 
the input Admit
    "SignSymptomMention": {},
// This is the RouteAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any Value for the 
input Admit
    "RouteAnnotation": {},
// This is the DateAnnotation Object which doesn't have any Value for the 
input Admit
    "DateAnnotation": {},
// This is the MeasurementAnnotation Object. which doesn't have any Value for 
the input Admit
    "MeasurementAnnotation": {},
// This is the RelationDetails Object. which doesn't have 1 Child object 
Value  for the input Admit
    "RelationDetails": {
        **"RELATIONS:":** [
            "\n"
        ]
    },
// This is the TimeMention. which doesn't have 1 Child object Value  for the 
input Admit
    "TimeMention": {},
// This is the ProcedureMention. which doesn't have 1 Child object Value  for 
the input Admit
    "ProcedureMention": {},
// This is the StrengthUnitAnnotation object. which doesn't have 1 Child 
object Value  for the input Admit
    "StrengthUnitAnnotation": {},
// This is the Health Care activity Object. which doesn't have 1 Child object 
Value  for the input Admit
    "Health Care activity": {
        **"Hospital admission":** [
            "start:1",
            "end:3",
            "polarity:1",
            "[codingScheme: SNOMEDCT_US, code: 32485007, cui: C0184666, 
semanticType: Health Care Activity, tui: T058, preferredtext: Hospital 
admission]"
        ]
    },
// This is the AnalysisText object which doesn't have 1 Child object Value  
for the input Admit
    "AnalysisText": {
        **"AnalysisText":** [
            "admit\n  ",
            "admit\n  "
        ]
    }
}
```

I have bolded** the child objects which will change dynamically based on the 
input. Currently i have given Admit as the input in Postmantool

Comment: Are you just trying to get the array found at `Others["Health Care Activity~T058~Hospital admission"]` without knowing the string `Health Care Activity~T058~Hospital admission`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer  Thanks for ur reply.... yes... After parseing of json it creates  others as parent object and within it it has health care activity child object (which is dynamically changing name based on the input) and it has array in which i need preferred text value. I am trying to get the preffered text value from parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve all the child objects values without knowing the keys using `Object.values`. This will be an array of all the values of all the children. So in the case of your object you can access the array with:

```js
let Admit = {
    "Allergy": {},
    "Others": {
        "Health Care Activity~T058~Hospital admission": [
                "codingScheme: SNOMEDCT_US",
                "code: 32485007",
                "cui: C0184666",
                "semanticType: Health Care Activity",
                "tui: T058",
                "preferredtext: Hospital admission"
            ]
    },
     "AnatomicalSiteMention": {}
     // etc...
}

let othersObj = Admit.Others
// children will have all the values of `others` children
// you don't need to know 'Health Care Activity~T058~Hospital admission' 
let children = Object.values(othersObj)
console.log(children[0])
```

You just need to be careful that you know *how many* children there might be. The about assumed that there was only one so we could access it with `children[0]`.